# Rider "Expression is always false" warning on bit-wise and

Tags: c#, resharper, rider

Why Rider gives *`"Expression is always false"`* warning on the below code?

```cs
bool b = (await Method1()) &
                  (await Method2()) &
                  (await Method3());
```

Method1 and Method2 and Method3 are the same.

```cs
private async Task<bool> Method1()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: may be you should email this question to their support guys... ;) I wonder what they would answer.

Comment: `&` is not *bitwise* here, but long computation scheme: first *all* `Method` will be exectuted and only then, combined by `and`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, you are right. If I change ```&``` to ```&&``` in that expression, there wouldn't be any warning.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the code analysis of Rider. I can confirm that Rider gives that warning on my end as well. I would report it to them if I were you.